# Programmatically creating variables in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically set a global (module) variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable)

I have a class called Variable defined as so:

```
class Variable():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self._value = None
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to create 26 capital single letter instances of Variable like this:

```
A = Variable('A')
B = Variable('B')
...
Z = Variable('Z')
```

So far I've tried various solutions, and the best I've come up with is:

```
from string import uppercase
for char in uppercase:
    exec "%s = %s" % (char, Variable(str(char))) in None
```

However, this doesn't run and gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Dev\python\truthtable\truthtable.py", line 7, in <module>
    exec "%s = %s" % (char, Variable(str(char))) in None
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Other than trying to create variables dynamically?

Comment: Er, the question name is a little wonky, I'm not too clued into these sorts of semantics.

Comment: @deeb -- I don't think Ignacio was referring to your title.

Comment: This was for a specific logic truth table involving 26 variables, but in the future creating them dynamically is the way to go.

Comment: I realize how terrible this code/idea is. :)

Comment: This was asked and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable :)

Comment: And the best answer is still "Don't". :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
from string import uppercase
_g = globals()
for char in uppercase:
    _g[char] = Variable(char)
```

Whether this is a *good* idea remains questionable :)

This only works for `globals()` (i.e. module level assignments), as the language definition explicitly states that modifying the dictionary returned by `locals()` may not actually change the value of any local variables.

You can also do something similar with the `__dict__` of a class or instance.

Comment: Modifying globals() is not a good idea: there is no official guarantee that this works: "This can fail: "there's no documented guarantee that changes to globals() will actually persist the changes to the underlying module. It works today, might break tomorrow." (Alex Martelli)

Comment: That's not correct - that caveat applies *only* to locals(). globals() is guaranteed to work correctly by the language spec.

Comment: @ncoghian: Here is the original comment by Alex, who is arguably an very seasoned Python programmer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable :)

Comment: Alex is *definitely* well worth listening to, but given the hoops we jump through as core devs to make sure that modifying module state via `globals()` doesn't break, he's wrong on this particular point. There's also plenty of standard library code that uses `globals()` that way. The written guarantee in this case is one of omission: for `locals()`, we include an explicit note to say that modifications are not reliable (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), but there is no such note for `globals()` (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.  I'm convinced about `globals()`  being updatable. :)

Answer (score 11):

The cleanest approach by far that I have ever seen is to directly add variables (i.e. attributes) to your program (i.e. main module), as answered in [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable):

```
import sys
from string import ascii_uppercase

this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
for char in ascii_uppercase:
    setattr(this_module, char, Variable(char))

print A  # Works!
```

**PS**: Python core developers worked hard so as to make modifying `globals()` possible (see the comments to ncoghlan's answer).  So, modifying `globals()` is an alternative.  I'm not sure why many people feel that it is not so clean, though (maybe because the fact that `globals()` can be modified is not *explicitly* documented?).

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not pretty but you can access the `globals()` dictionary directly:

```
for c in 'ABC':
    globals()[c] = Variable(c)
```

Comment: "Attribute assignment updates the module’s namespace dictionary, e.g., m.x = 1 is equivalent to m.__dict__["x"] = 1." (from http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `exec` for this, as the other answers show, but here is the problem with your original code:

```
for char in uppercase:
    exec "%s = %s" % (char, Variable(str(char))) in None
```

This will exec `A = A`, `B = B`, etc.  While this may be interesting if you're an ardent follower of Objectivism, python won't care too much for it.

You want to have the `Variable()` stuff inside the exec for it to matter:

```
for char in uppercase:
    exec "%s = Variable('%s')" % (char, char)
```

In the future, if you're trying to use `exec`, first try not to.  Second, print what you're execing -- that will help to debug.

Comment: No downvote, but there is a cleaner way (and likely faster way, if that matters), as made explicit in my answer.

Comment: Of course there is, I say not to do it this way in my answer. This is a fixed version of the original code that actually does use `exec`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to stick this into a global variable. It's horrid. Do this instead.

```
import string

variables = {}
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
    variables[x] = Variable(x)
```

The you access it from `variables['Q']`, for example.

If you want attribute access you can do:

```
class Variables(object): pass
```

and

```
variables = Variables()
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
    setattr(variables, x) = Variable(x)
```

But in that case I'd rather **create them dynamically in a Variables container class**.

```
import string

class Variable(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Variable %s>" % self.value

class Variables(object):
    def __getattr__(self, n):
        if n in string.ascii_uppercase:
            v = Variable(n)
            setattr(self, n, v)
            return v
        raise AttributeError("Variables instance has no attribute %s" % n)
```

Usage:

```
>>> v = Variables()
>>> v.G
<Variable G>
>>> v.Y
<Variable Y>
>>> v.G is v.G
True
```

Simple and clean, no ugly hacks (well, except a getattr, and it's not that ugly), and you don't even have to make the Variables you don't need.

Comment: While I agree that this is usually the way to go, there are definitely use cases for adding lots of objects directly into the local namespace, e.g. for math.  x==sin(w)*(y+exp(-z)) is worlds better than v.x==m.sin(v.w)*(v.y+m.exp(-v.z)).

Comment: Well, I think mathematicians obsession with one letter long variable names is a mistake in the first place. :) It's useful when you do your calculations on paper, or simplify/expand formulas. But in the actual implementation of a formula in a programing language? Nyaaahhhh'm skeptical... :-)

Comment: Maybe you can immediately remove all the "v." and "m." in my second expression and see the first expression, but I had to compare them almost character by character to be sure they were the same.  An extra letter for each variable and function, and a dot which makes me think multiplication.  I'm far more likely to miss an obvious error in the second form, as I have to overcome years of experience reading the standard form without extraneous characters strewn about.  Readability counts, as I heard someone say somewhere ;-), and that principle doesn't always tilt in favour of more characters.

Comment: @DSM: Well, you do have a point with the dot.

Comment: @Lennart: Interesting ideas!  Raising AttributeError for non-matching attribute names would be more robust (otherwise, illegal attribute names like in `v.x` return a well-defined None value).

Comment: @EOL: Absolutely, I just forgot it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import uppercase
for c in uppercase:
    locals()[c] = Variable(c)
print A
```

I'm not sure why you want to do this, though.

Comment: This can officially fail: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter." (from the documentation).