# No need for enums

Tags: python

I read a post recently where someone mentioned that there is no need for using enums in python. I'm interested in whether this is true or not.

For example, I use an enum to represent modem control signals:

```
class Signals:
  CTS = "CTS"
  DSR = "DSR"
  ...
```

Isn't it better that I use `if signal == Signals.CTS:` than `if signal == "CTS":`, or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to implement an 'enum' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-an-enum-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Signals.CTS` does seem better than "CTS". But Signals is not an enum, it's a class with specific fields. The claim, as I've heard it, is that you don't need a separate enum language construct, as you can do things like you've done in the question, or perhaps:

```
CTS, DSR, XXX, YYY, ZZZ = range(5)
```

If you have that in a signals module, it can be imported as used in a similar fashion, e.g., `if signal == signals.CTS:`. This is used in several modules in the standard library, including the re and os modules.

Comment: @MattH There are a bunch of options, I wasn't intending to be comprehensive.

Comment: @MattH: I think that you have a good idea.  I would suggest that you post an answer.  I would +1 it.  :)

Comment: I like having the strings so that I can log the signals with print("Data: " + str(Signals.CTS))

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: I would like to add that users of the module where this is done still get the explicit `module.CTS`, etc. syntax.  This is what is done in many standard Python modules (re, os,…).

Comment: @EOL I've edited it in. If you know other modules that use the approach, please add them to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your exact example, I guess it would be okay to use defined constants, as it would raise an error, when the constant is not found, alas a typo in a string would not.

I guess there is an at least equal solution using object orientation.

BTW: `if "CTS":` will *always* be `True`, since only empty strings are interpreted as `False`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you use values of `Signal.CTS`, `Signal.DSR` as data. For example if you send these strings to actual modem. If this is true, then it would be a good idea to have aliases defined as you did, because external interfaces tend to change or be less uniform when you would expect. Otherwise if you don't ever use symbols values then you can skip layer of abstraction and use strings directly.

The only thing is not to mix internal symbols and external data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have meaningful string constants (`CTS = "CTS"`, etc.), you can simply do:

```
for constant_name in ('CTS', 'DSR'):  # All constant names go here
    globals()[constant_name] = constant_name
```

This defines variables CTS dans DSR with the values you want. (Reference about the use of `globals()`: [Programmatically creating variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859217/programmatically-creating-variables-in-python).)

**Directly defining your constants at the top level of a module is done in many standard library modules** (like for instance the `re` and `os` modules [`re.IGNORECASE`, etc.]), so this approach is quite clean.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could explain the down vote, especially since I agree with the other, non-downvoted answers that say that using global variables is fine.   This would be useful to readers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot more to load on enumerations (setting arbitrary values, bitwise operations, whitespace-d descriptions).

Please read below very short post, check the enum class offered, and judge yourself.

[Python Enum Post](http://oferelboher.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/python-enumeration-i-recently-needed-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do we *need* Enums in Python?  Do we need an html module, a database module, or a bool type?

I would classify Enums as a nice-to-have, not a must-have.

However, part of the reason Enums finally showed up (in [Python 3.4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/)) is because they a such a nice-to-have that many folk reimplemented enums by hand.  With so many private and public versions of enumerations, interoperability becomes an issue, standard use becomes an issue, etc., etc.

So to answer your question:  No, we don't *need* an Enum type.  But we now have one anyway.  There's even a [back-ported version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).