# Django default settings convention for pluggable app?

Tags: python, django, configuration

What's a djangonautic way of handling default settings in an app if one isn't defined in `settings.py`?

I've currently placed a `default_settings` file in the app and I've considered a few options. I'm leaning towards the first option, but there may be pitfalls I'm not aware of in using `globals()`

I've mostly seen apps do a `FOO = getattr(settings, 'FOO', False)` at the top of the file that uses the setting but I think there are readability/repetition problems with this approach if the values / names are long.

---

**1: Place settings in a function and iterate over locals / set globals**

```
def setup_defaults():
    FOO = 'bar'
    for key, value in locals().items():
        globals()[key] = getattr(settings, key, value)

setup_defaults()
```

Pros:

- Only have to write var name once to pull default of same name from django settings.

Cons:

- Not used to using globals() and don't know of any implications

---

**2: Write `getattr(settings, 'MY_SETTING', default_settings.MY_SETTING)` every call**

Pros: 
- Very clear.

Cons: - Repetitive

---

**3: Always define settings as `FOO = getattr(settings, 'FOO', '...setting here...')`**

Pros:
- Defaults are always overridden

Cons:

- Repetitive (must define var twice - once in string form, once in var)
- Setting is not as readable since it's now the third argument

---

**4: Create utility function to `get_or_default(setting)`**

Pros:

- Simple
- Don't have to repeat string representation of setting

Cons:

- Have to call it

---

**5: Create a settings class**

```
class Settings(object):
    FOO = 'bar'

    def __init__(self):
         # filter out the startswith('__') of 
         # self.__dict__.items() / compare to django.conf.settings?

my_settings = Settings()
```

Cons:

- Can't do from foo.bar.my_settings import FOO (actually, that's a terrible deal breaker!)

---

I'd love to hear feedback.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, haha, good point! I've conjured up a con. Let's just say it's visually inconsistent with other constants..

Comment: Almost none of these seem to work anymore in Django 1.11.

Comment: Djangonautic, +1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think it's quite common to create a `settings.py` in your app's package, where you define your settings like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
FOO = getattr(settings, 'FOO', "default_value")
```

In your app you can import them from your app's `settings` module:

```
from myapp.settings import *

def print_foo():
    print FOO
```

But I think everybody agrees that Django is lacking a better generic architecture for this! If you're looking for a more sophisticated way to handle this, there are some third party apps for this like [django-appconf](https://github.com/jezdez/django-appconf), but it's your  decision if you want to introduce one more dependency for your app or not!

### Updated for 2020

In `settings.py`, put `settings.*` before the property.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.FOO = getattr(settings, 'FOO', "default_value")
```

Comment: Excellent answer. This can be extended to live in `models.py` as well, see [this tutorial for an overview](http://blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/26/developing-reusable-django-apps-app-settings.html).

Comment: Although this is good, I had a problem when I came to test the code that's using the setting. `django.test.override_settings` doesn't seem to play nicely  with this method - if I override the setting for a test, this isn't picked up by my code which is importing it from `myapp.settings`.

Comment: @PhilGyford same here. I solved this by setting my `MYAPP_SETTING` on the main `django.conf.settings` object as well. And then, in the `myapp` code, I'll always import `django.conf.settings`, and use `MYAPP_SETTING` from there. It works, but, modifies settings object at runtime...dont know if this should be ok - a solution like django-appconf will probably handle this better?

Comment: @benzkji you can also take a look at https://github.com/Genida/django-appsettings (I'm the author), a django app that can handle this issue without suffering performance loss

Comment: also, for those who dont want another dependency: `reload(settings)` (your own settings)...within an override block, and good you are!

Comment: or instead of `reload` just use `AppConfig.ready` as mentioned in another answer. A real saver.

Answer (score 17):

It seems that every solution I see there tends to create an internal copy of application settings, proxy, wrap or whatever. This is confusing and creates problems when settings are [modified in run time like they do in tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings).

To me all settings belong in `django.conf.settings` and only there. You should not read them from somewhere else nor copy it for later use (as they may change). You should set them once and don't bother about defaults later on.

I understand the impulse to drop the app prefix when app setting is used internally, but this also is IMHO a bad idea. When in trouble looking for `SOME_APP_FOO` will not yield results, as it's used just as `FOO` internally. Confusing right? And for what, few letters? Remember [that explicit is better](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)?

IMHO the best way is to just set those defaults in Django's own settings, and why don't use piping that is already there? No module import hooks or hijacking `models.py` being always imported to initialize some extra and complicated meta class piping.

Why not use [AppConfig.ready](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.ready) for setting defaults?

```
class FooBarConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo_bar'

    def ready(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        settings = settings._wrapped.__dict__
        settings.setdefault('FOO_BAR_SETTING', 'whatever')
```

Or better yet define them in clean simple way in a separate module and import them as (or close to how) [Settings class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py#L99) does it:

```
class FooBarConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo_bar'

    def ready(self):
        from . import app_settings as defaults
        from django.conf import settings
        for name in dir(defaults):
            if name.isupper() and not hasattr(settings, name):
                setattr(settings, name, getattr(defaults, name))
```

I'm not sure use of `__dict__` is the best solution, but you get the idea, you can always user `hasattr`/`setattr` combo to get the efect.

This way your app settings are:

1. exposed to others — if they should rely on them in some rare cases, if of course apps are configured in order rely on each other
2. read normally as any other setting
3. nicely declared in their own module
4. lazy enough
5. controlled how they're are set in `django.conf.settings` — you can implement some transposition of names if you want to

PS. There is a [warning about not modifying settings in run time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime) but it does not explain why. So I think this one time, during initialization may be a reasonable exception ;)

PS2. Don't name the separate module just `settings` as this may get confusing when you import `settings` from `django.conf`.

Comment: not sure why this does not have more upvotes. definitely the only way to go. if `app_settings.py` does not work for unit testing, then it's not a solution.. this one works perfectly (using `hasattr` and `setattr`)

Comment: not modifying settings at run time has everything to do with multi-threaded applications. If you know what you're doing there's no harm in modifying settings at run time.

Comment: Excellent solution! I'll inspire myself from this

Comment: but what if you want to make available the `app_settings` in app templates via a custom app `context_preprocessor` ?

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

In myapp/settings.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

FOO = 'bar'
BAR = 'baz'

_g = globals()
for key, value in _g.items():
    _g[key] = getattr(settings, key, value)
```

In myapp/other.py:

```
import myapp.settings

print myapp.settings.FOO
```

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859312/1062565) by ncoghlan, I feel ok using globals() this way.

Comment: Isnn't this setting all kinds of stuff on the globals

Answer (score 3):

you can use [django-zero-settings](https://github.com/aasmpro/django-zero-settings) which lets you define your defaults and a setting key for user settings to auto-override defaults, has auto-import strings, removed settings management, cache, pre-checks, etc.

to create app settings like your example:

```
from zero_settings import ZeroSettings

app_settings = ZeroSettings(
    key="APP",
    defaults={
        "FOO": "bar"
    },
)
```

then you can use it like:

```py
from app.settings import app_settings

print(app_settings.FOO)  # which prints bar
```

user settings will auto override defaults, like:

```py
# this is settings.py, Django settings file
SECRET_KEY = "some_key"
# other settings ...
# the key `APP` is same key arg for ZeroSettings
APP = {
    "FOO": "not_bar"
}
```

and then:

```py
from app.settings import app_settings

print(app_settings.FOO)  # this time you get not_bar
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to Phil Gyford's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428556/django-default-settings-convention-for-pluggable-app#comment-62974382), exposing the problem of settings not overwritten in tests (since already imported in modules), what I did was to define an `AppSettings` class in `__init__.py` with:

- an `__init__` method to initialize each setting to `None`
- a `load` method to load every settings from getters
- static getters for each setting

Then in the code:

```
from . import AppSettings

def in_some_function():
    some_setting = AppSettings.get_some_setting()
```

Or if you want to load them all in once (but overriding settings in tests won't work for the impacted module):

```
from . import AppSettings

app_settings = AppSettings()
app_settings.load()

def in_some_function():
   print(app_settings.some_setting)
```

You can then use the `override_settings` decorator in your tests, and still have some DRY and clear way of using app settings, at the cost of more instructions executed each time you want to get a setting (just for tests...).

Comment: +1 for the effort to write an answer for this very specific problem. But, it seems a bit complicated? See my comment, for a lightweight (but maybe bad practice?) approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428556/django-default-settings-convention-for-pluggable-app#comment82825787_8429282

Comment: @benzkji you are right, it's a bit complicated, see an enhanced version of this answer here: https://github.com/Genida/django-appsettings

Answer (score -1):

Number 3 is best because it is the most simple one. And very consistent look.

Number 1: it is easy to overlook it. If I'll open your code and I won't scroll to the bottom I'll miss it and I will think that settings can't be overridden in my own module.

Number 2: is not only repetitive, it is harder to read because it is too long, also default values will be defined multiple time and scattered all over your code.

Number 4: non-consistent-look, repetitive calls.

Number 5: Non consistent, we expect settings to be defined in a module not in a class. Well at least I do expect to find to be defined as module because I've seen many apps using method 3, and I use it my self so I might be biased.

Comment: Comment on #1, easily fixed by putting a comment at the top!

Comment: Which one is number 1 or 2? You could have left your comments in the referenced answer