# Use items in a list as new dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate through the items in a list:

```
cities = ['San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'Phoenix', 'Las Vegas', 'Dallas', 'Miami', 'Washington DC', 'New York']
```

in order to create new dictionaries with the city name i.e. `Phoenix = {}`.

```
for city in cities:
    city = {}
```

But instead a dictionary named `city` is created:

```
>>> city
{}
>>> type(city)
<class 'dict'>
```

No dictionaries with the name of the city are created:

```
>>> Phoenix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#122>", line 1, in <module>
    Phoenix
NameError: name 'Phoenix' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Briefly: just make a dictionary to hold those dictionaries.

Comment: What do you mean?  Iterate through the items in a list, create some dict and use them as the variable name?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Sorry I wasn't more clear.  I would like the entries in the list to be the variable name for new dictionary entries.

Comment: Do that with a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, do what with a dictionary?

Comment: Read the linked duplicate - its top-voted, accepted answer explains the structure.

Comment: @JDRJ, a variable in python cannot have space in it, so city name like ``Los Angeles`` cannot be a variable name. If all the city names are valid variable names you can check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859217/programmatically-creating-variables-in-python for exactly what you wanted, though as TigerhawkT3 suggested you probably shouldn't do so in the first place.