# Reducing variable name duplication when using os.getenv

Tags: python

I'm frequently finding myself writing repetitive-feeling code in the style below (as it happens, inside a Django `settings.py`, but the question is meant much more generally):

```
STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID')
STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET')
# et cetera
```

Naturally there are plenty of occasions where I don't want my local variable name to match the name of the environment variable, but it's happening enough that I'm wondering if there's a nice way to avoid the name duplication.

The below code works for me:

```
_locals = locals()
def f(x):
    _locals[x] = os.getenv(x)

f('TERM')

print TERM
```

but I have no intention of using this in production, as, to quote [the Python documentation on `locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified;

so I'm wondering if there exists a valid "supported"/"approved" solution, and if so, what it might look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing: [How to programmatically set a global (module) variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable)

```
import sys, os

opts = (
    'STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID', 
    'STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET'
)

module = sys.modules[__name__]
for o in opts:
    setattr(module, o, os.getenv(o))
```

In the comments of that referenced answer, it links to another that suggests `globals()` is reliable for updating directly as well...

```
_g = globals()
for o in opts:
    _g[o] = os.getenv(o)
```

Comment: That'd do it, thanks very much - had a hard time trying to find the right vocabulary for what I wanted to do, so totally missed the other question

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's partly a matter of taste, but I would tend to put these in a dictionary, so:

```
STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID')
STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET')
```

would become:

```
envars['STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID'] = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_ID')
envars['STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = os.getenv('STACKEXCHANGE_CLIENT_SECRET')
```

Or, you could just use the `os.environ` dictionary directly.

Comment: This would totally work in a general case. Unfortunately the OP mentions the settings.py of a django project which is expecting them to be global variables. Kinda has him by the ghoulies on this one.

Comment: Yeah I was perhaps insufficiently clear with my requirements, I just didn't want it to be interpreted too narrowly as a Django-related question, but the global-ness is definitely a requirement; thanks though