# Defining multiple models in Pyomo/AMPL

Tags: python, ampl, pyomo

I am trying to set up (and solve) multiple optimizations problems in `Pyomo/AMPL`. For this I need to define the models first, for `AMPL`:

```
model model_1.mod

model model_2.mod

model model_3.mod

...

model model_n.mod
```

for `Pyomo`:

```
model_1 = ConcreteModel()

model_2 = ConcreteModel()

...

model_n = ConcreteModel()
```

I was wondering if there is an automatic way to do this, whether with a for loop, or some indexing so that if n=100 I don't have to write 100 `model_k = ConcreteModel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load AMPL models in a loop using `commands` instead of `model`:

```
for {i in 1..n}
  commands('model_' & i & '.mod');
```

Similar thing can be done in Pyomo using [standard Python's mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429814/how-to-programmatically-set-a-global-module-variable):

```
g = globals()
for i in range(n + 1):
  g['model_' + str(i)] = ConcreteModel()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can simply create a list of models:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

models = []
for i in range(100):
  models.append( ConcreteModel() )
```

Then, each model can be accessed by indexing the list:  `models[19]` is the 19th model.